Dimension of division ring over a sub division ring
Let $L$ be a division ring ("skew field") and $K$ a sub division ring. Now suppose that $L$, as a left vector space over $K$, has finite dimension $m$. Does $L$, as a right vector space over $K$, also has dimension $m$ ?
How about the $m = 2$ case ?

When $m=2$, can't you just check whether $1$ any element of $L - K$ forms a basis?  (I haven't really thought about it.)
